# Visual Studio 2010 C# - application with centralized database - development

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I've started working on my database **desktop** application. The goal is to have one centralized database, so that each employee could connect.

My goals:

- Centralized database on SQL Server 2008 Express
- Use Sql to Linq
- First run of application should create structure of database on server.

**Now my question: how to do the last point?**

I know that I can generate sql script via SQL Managment Studio and then execute it, but maybe there is some better way?

Comment: Why would you want a database on each user's computer?  That seems very odd.  It also seems to contradict "the goal is to have one centralized database."

Comment: Read it again ;-) I haven't written that I want to database on each computer, but "The goal is to have one centralized database, so that each employee could connect"

Comment: have a look at Entity Framework Code First. That is a modern approach in which you first write your models. If you have your Database connection properly setup, the first time your application is started it will create the datebase infrastructure for your models

Comment: I'm sorry... I've forgotten to write that I'm working on desktop application, not web application, so creating database by customer would be odd for me :).

Comment: Having an application create the database seems like a terrible idea to me.  You have little control over the timing, versioning, storage options, etc.

Comment: I don't understand, let's assume that customer buys software and wants to start using it, so you tells me that he should open sql server managment studio and create database by himself? I think that if there is no database at specified location, then user should have option to create it from application. I've never seen something like that.

Comment: Generally, even in desktop apps, with a shared db the db is setup before a client connects to it. It's a separate setup and configuration. For the most part you want to keep your desktop app's db permissions as limited as possible. Allowing it to have admin priveleges so it can create a db is opening you up to a world of security hell.

Comment: @MikeParkhill - you're right, I haven't thought about it. Valuable comment, but also I assume, that first person to run application would be administrator, so it should create database and create admin account.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into introducing a web service layer between your desktop clients and your db. It will give you more flexibility with security and rolling out schema updates. If you have a large desktop install base coordinating upgrades can be a real challenge. Web services give you easy versioning options that allow staggered roll outs.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments said, I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but if you have one centralized database machine and you want to create a new database per user upon the first connection, then you could create one canonical/template database and the clone it via scripting on the first connect.

Your UI would say something like "Please wait while we create your new database..." and you'd run CREATE scripts for the database/tables/stored procedures/views/etc.

Just remember it might be a major pain to update the schemas of these databases once the cat is out of the bag.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP wants everyone to share a common instance, he justs wants it to be created the first time someone tries to connect to it. But, if he wanted them all to have their own instance on the same server then your points are bang on.

Comment: I guess it's confusing because they'll all share a common instance, but having it created on the first connect ... are you rolling out something to a business where they have like 100 users? And you have many installations? Because what happens when the second user connects? You know not to create the database?

Comment: Well whatever the reason, I think you already hit the nail on the head. You can script the creation upon the first connect. I'm sure we could think of more creative approaches, but that seems the best and simplest.